# How do I set a URL in TORRC file I keep getting index of it needs to point to the main directory

Tags: configuration

I am having an issue with routing my onion site to the right directory.
For instance, it is going to the index of or root directory of the FTP for the site and not the site itself.
Here are some pictures
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HMZi.jpg

I need it to point to 127.0.0.1/wonderland/index.php

Comment: This is an issue with your Apache config. You probably need to update the `DocumentRoot` and/or `Directory` options to point to the correct path. If you post your Apache config and your directory structure, someone might be able to help more.

Comment: Could you show me how to configure the Document root directory.

Comment: Here are the files I am presently working with.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Sw2faW7 Photos of files that I am working with,